# Partitioning Mariadb small error on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/range-partitioning-type/

Tags: mariadb

Please correct me but I've located a small error on the Mariadb documentation on  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/range-partitioning-type/

The second example under Use cases has a superfluous UNIX_TIMESTAMP in the PARTION BY RANGE line. As the column timestamp already is a unix timestamp UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) will not work, will it? The line should read

```
 PARTITION BY RANGE( TimeStamp )
```

Not sure how to get in touch with the ppl. that write the manual.

Comment: You could try the "contact" link at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question that can be answered.

Comment: It could be and is answered.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are wrong. Check the documentation:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/

This is a `TIMESTAMP`:

> A timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ffffff.

This is UNIX_TIMESTAMP:

> 1374490205

Comment: Yeah, the column names in those examples are confusing.

Comment: My mistake, Thanks for checking on me, Swisstone.